# Complete Software development in diagrams

Tags: uml, visio

I always think that we draw diagrams of software that we want to design. Then we code in (text) files. This is followed by the process in which the design change and the code has to change accordingly OR the code change and the design has to be changed.

Any ways the design (the diagram) and the code both are two different entities and both need to be in sync with each other.

Is there a system in which we generate diagrams for our software AND THEN PUT CODE DIRECTLY INTO THE DIAGRAM (AND NOT IN TEXT FILES)? and then may be the flow of data etc is visualized in the same diagram. 
We debug the diagram and not the text file.
Any views friends?

Comment: An interesting question, but probably belongs in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. There have been many attempts at visual programming, but not much success, or at least not much popular uptake. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_programming_language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia has a list of UML tools ready for you:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools#Features

In the "Languages generated" column you see for what languages the tools can generate code from models you have built. In the "Reverse engineered languages" you see what languages the tools can generate models from.

One should also mention, that all tools (at least those that I know of) differ in their way of interpreting the UML specification and at least most of the tools violate the specification in some way. That's not a big deal until you want to migrate your models from one tool to another. Then it'll be virtually impossible.

Comment: I think My questionn was not very clear.. I want that we should manually code but inside the diagram since each piece of diagram show an execution of a system. and just like the diagram reflect the system similarly the code inside the diagram will reflect the flow of information

Comment: That sounds awesome and more like a visual programming language in itself! Programming via the diagram.... see the wiki link that @DNA posted as comment to your original question! Maybe you should write/build on yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a meta question about opinion then probably best ask a meta site or a forum!

However if it is a question about code generation from your UML diagrams. You absolutely can do that.

[Code generation in Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/support/faq/code_generation.html)

This is one tool I have used before. Part of the meta data for each class is the language you are describing it for. You can then sync the diagram to the code or the code to the diagram...

Most of these tools however are not as good as to remove the need to hand coding IMHO. I have yet to use these kind of tools for anything but building skeletons when you first start to code!

Answer (score 0):

I've tested and used bouml with c++ (which now is no more open source).

It can reverse your code, almots 95% perfectly, except for extrange definitions that are not usually reversed. But from there all is manual. You have to draw your class diagrams and secuence diagrams by hand.

Comment: ok thanks but i think one day people will code IN DIAGRAMS and look back to today and think how could people code with out diagrams... just like we look at binary programming of computers